# Compare shapes with Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

Tags: time-series, goodness-of-fit, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, java

I have two time series, both 100 points length: I would like to perform the goodness of fit to know if these two series have same or similar shape or if they differs significantly.

I have read about the K/S test for 1 sample and it seems it compares the serie with a normal or gaussian distribution.

I do not want to compare my two series with two standard gaussian shapes, I only want to know if they are similar or different.

I have found this class for the K/S test

http://www.jsc.nildram.co.uk/api/index.html

Here are my questions:

1) is the K/S two sample test the best one for non parametric test with series.length()< 150 points?

2) are there other statistical test to compare shapes?

3) the jsc Java class has some different methods, which one should I have to use to return how much my series differs?

Thanks all.

Comment: Your language may confuse many readers, because the K-S test compares *empirical probability distributions* to each other or to a reference distribution, whereas in most time series applications the question of interest is to compare how the two series are varying over time. Although similar-looking graphs of values may be involved in both kinds of comparisons, they are totally different. Which one do you really want to ask about?

Comment: Hi whuber thanks for your reply: since I am not an expert in statistic, I simply would like to know if my two series have same shape or if they differ, and possibily how much serie1 is different from serie2.

Is K/S test suitable for this purpose? And if not, what other test can I use?

Comment: This is a vast subject, Alberto, as you can find by following the links from the [tag:time-series] tag. Rather than asking whether some particular test will work (no, the K-S test is irrelevant here), you will be more successful by describing your data and stating in plain, non-technical terms what you would like to learn about them. Time series can behave in many ways--they can trend, form cycles, suddenly change, exhibit more or less variability, and so on--so you need to be much more specific about what you mean by "similar" and why you care.

Comment: Thanks whuber I really appreciate your detailed reply: will try to be more specific about my needs.